# Typeform: Country region state questions

Tags: api, typeform

I'm new to `Typeform` and I want to add Country region state questions, in which region is related to country and so on, in other words when I select a country I must get only state in that country in the state dropdown.

Any tips please, I didn't find anything on the web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve such a thing you would need to use what Typeform calls [Logic Jump](https://help.typeform.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029116392-What-is-Logic-Jump-).
And create a state question for each country that would have states (example: US, Canada,...)

Then you can create a Logic Jump with conditions

`If **country** selected is **United States of America** go to question States of America`

`If **country** selected is **Canada** go to question States of Canada`

And so on for each country you want to have.

Unfortunately there is no way to make this dynamic. You have to "hard code" all the questions.

You can always use the [API](https://developer.typeform.com/create/reference/create-form/) to programmatically build this form.

Comment: Doing it this way for each country is actually not efficient, it would take forever to just set a simple form. Thank you anyways